# Why CLONE_NEWUSER clone flag in Go will cause invalid argument error

Tags: go, clone

I want to test the `CLONE_NEWUSER` flag. My kernel version is greater than 3.8 (because `CLONE_NEWUSER` not the feature <3.8).

When I run the code, it says invalid argument error:

```
2020/10/18 23:09:59 fork/exec /usr/bin/sh: invalid argument
exit status 1
```

This is the source code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("sh")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWIPC | syscall.CLONE_NEWPID | syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER | syscall.CLONE_NEWNS | syscall.CLONE_NEWNET,
    }

    cmd.SysProcAttr.Credential = &syscall.Credential{
        Uid: uint32(0),
        Gid: uint32(0),
    }

    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cross-compliation error.

The executable is built for different OS configurations.
Refer: http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is centos7, it disables User Namespace by default. Use the following commands to enable it:

```
# echo 640 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces
```

It maybe help you.